# Why does the crypto module not have 'secp256k' curve when I try to use it in electronJs?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, electron, diffie-hellman

I get this error when I try to use secp256k1 (default crypto module) in electronJs. I do not get this error when I am not using electron.
[I also logged all of the available curves. There's no secp256k1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHyoJ.png)

[Also, here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkYQ5.png)

Comment: Please add your code and error as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: It looks like the underlying library or wrapper library simply doesn't allow that curve to be used. Note that before bitcoin the binary secp256k1 curve was mostly unused. Most applications use(d) secp256r1 instead. Please provide all the runtime environment details that you have.